# controlM variable for YYYYMM?

Tags: control-m

I'm using ControlM and in a command, I would like to find a variable that gives me the date in this format : YYYYMM

I found there is %%$DATE variable but it gives YYYYMMDD

Thanks for you help

Comment: In one = VARIABLE NAME="%%YRMON" VALUE="%%SUBSTR %%$ODATE 1 6"

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to define and concatenate a variable that will represent the date in such a format.

These are available:

- Day DD, %%DAY,
- Month MM, %%MONTH,
- Year YY, %%YEAR,
- Year YYYY, %%$YEAR

Comment: In order to have two variables next to each other without white space you need to terminate the first with a period. For example “%%$YEAR.%%MONTH” should achieve your goal.

Comment: Furthermore, you can keep your "customized" dates (built in the way described) in the LIBMEMSYM (or LIBMEMSYMs)..

Answer (score 2):

**Prefer %%$OYEAR AND %%OMONTH over %%$YEAR and %%MONTH**

I suggest using the variables **%%$OYEAR** and **%%OMONTH** over **%%$YEAR** and **%%MONTH**. The reason is that date variables beginning with **O** refer to processing dates and do not necessarily coincide with the system date. For this case you could use any of the following options:

```
 1. YYYYMM = %%$OYEAR.%%OMONTH 
 2. YYYYMM = %%SUBSTRING %%$ODATE 1 6
```

The **$** symbol preceding the variable %%$OYEAR or %%$ODATE indicates that the year is returned in 4-digit format, instead of OYEAR or ODATE which print the year with only 2 digits.

The dot (.) character is used for concatenate variables.

For example: For the order day May 29, 2020.

```
 1. %%$ODATE would print 20200529 
 2. %%ODATE would print  200529
```

Comment: `%%CALCDATE` also follows the same behaviour. Use `%%$CALCDATE` to get the year with 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You should add dot in each end of parameter

```
YYYY = %%$OYEAR.
MM = %%OMONTH.
YYYYMM = %%$OYEAR.%%OMONTH.
```

Comment: Please describe what the dot does, and preferably, link to the documentation. Also, check your spelling before posting an answer.